# Source.fromResource() works locally, but throws java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException on server

Tags: java, scala, character-encoding

I'm using this code to read a resource:

```
  val source = Source.fromResource(pathWithoutSlash)
  val lines:Seq[String] = (for (l <- source.getLines() if ! l.trim.isEmpty) yield l.trim).toList
```

This code works fine when I run it locally - but on the server, it fails with:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
    at java.base/java.nio.charset.CoderResult.throwException(CoderResult.java:274)
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:339)
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
    at java.base/java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:185)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:326)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:392)
    at scala.io.BufferedSource$BufferedLineIterator.hasNext(BufferedSource.scala:70)
```

I'm guessing its because the file does contain some accented characters, like: `éclair's` , and probably the default charset being used on the server is different from what I have locally.

My question is, how can I change the charset on the server so it matches whatever I have locally (and how can I check what I have locally)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd assume that the implicit [`Codec`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.1/scala/io/Codec$.html) value that you can see with

```
println(implicitly[scala.io.Codec])
```

is different on your server. If I understand it correctly, it should evaluate to `scala.io.Codec.fallbackSystemCodec`. Just pass the appropriate `Codec` explicitly (the [`fromResource`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.1/scala/io/Source$.html#fromResource(resource:String,classLoader:ClassLoader)(implicitcodec:scala.io.Codec):scala.io.BufferedSource) method takes an implicit `Codec` in the second parameter list), e.g.:

```
val source = Source.fromResource(pathWithoutSlash)(Codec.UTF8)
```

Comment: Any ideas how the fallback system codec could be changed? Is there a jvm setting?

Comment: @ClickUpvote From the code, it looks as if it's essentially a wrapper around [`java.nio.charset.Charset.defaultCharset()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#defaultCharset()). Maybe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361975/setting-the-default-java-character-encoding) is something useful.